# Responding to HttpPost in C#

Tags: java, c#, http

I have two apps, one Java and another C#. With Java I'm sending HttpPost and waiting for response like this:

```
try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(arg0[0]);
        httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(arg0[1]));
        httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.v(TAG, "Sent: " + arg0[1] + " to " + arg0[0]);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Post is sent to C# when I receive it properly with this code:

```
socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);

                info.Text = "Capturing on: " + ifaces.SelectedItem.ToString();
                capIface = ifaces.SelectedItem.ToString();
                socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ifs[ifaces.SelectedIndex], 0));

                socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, true);

                byte[] byTrue = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
                byte[] byOut = new byte[4];

                socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, byTrue, byOut);
                byte[] data = new byte[4096];
                socket.BeginReceive(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
```

and

```
private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            int rec = socket.EndReceive(ar);

            ParseData(data, rec);

            if (capture)
            {
                data = new byte[4096];
                socket.BeginReceive(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), null);
            }
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error receiving packets", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

But I don't know hot to send HttpResponse from C# application so that I can read it in Java. I would be very grateful for help.

Comment: Won't that interfere with socket.BeginReceive?

Comment: You won't use sockets. *HttpListener* can give you everything you need to act like a web server.

Comment: Will definitely check that out. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this. Problem is, I'm running XAMPP server which receives messages that are later relayed to C# application. When XAMPP is listening on a port, HttpListener cannot access it.